# Regex and pattern in a preg_match - PHP to fit 123-23-345

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm not very good into finding the right automation of a regex, to generate different expression, but when this comes to scripting in PHP, it becomes a pain in my ass. I can't proove myself able to write a pattern in preg_match that would 'fit' expressions like: 123-23-345...123-34-456....12-234-56.....It should be 3 groups of digits, where every group, individualy is left-to-right sorted, and every next group hasn't a digit bigger than the biggest digit of the previous group. This: 123-23-456 would be wrong, as 2 in 23 is smaller than 3 in 123. 123-43-45 is wrong again because 43 should be 34...

This should help me validate a field that may have only that type of content. It should be a regex validation not a function for parsing, splitting...

Comment: This is not really an ideal problem for regular expressions.

Comment: definitely not a regex work. regex is about patterns, and what you want to do involves semantics.

Comment: How long is every group ? {1,3} or unlimited ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there will be no regex-only solution, I think.
So here I coded the function you need:

```
function isValidDigitExpression($string) {
    $flag = preg_match('/^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)$/', $string, $matches);
    if (!$flag) return false;

    // Check correct sorting by splitting digit string to array
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
         $block[$i] = str_split($matches[$i]);
         $compare = $block[$i];
         sort($compare);
         if ($compare != $block[$i]) return false;
    }

    // Compare Min and Max digits of neighboring digit blocks
    return (max($block[1]) <= min($block[2]) and max($block[2]) <= min($block[3]));
}

$string = "123-34-356"; // Failure, because 3 < 4 comparing Block 2 and Block 3
echo isValidDigitExpression($string) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using only `preg_` function, you'd need to use some other condition matching too.

```
<?php
  $str = "123-34-456";
  preg_match( "/^.*?(\d)\-(\d).*?(\d)\-(\d)/", $str, $matches );
  $flag = true;
  if( $matches[2] < $matches[1] )
      $flag = false;
  if( $matches[4] < $matches[3] )
      $flag = false;
  echo ( !$flag ) ? "ERROR" : "NO ERROR";
?>
```

Similarly, you can match the numbers in respective sections, iterate over all the literals and again use the flag for not-matching values.

Something like this:

```
<?php
  $str = "132-34-456";
  preg_match( "/^(\S+)\-(\S+)\-(\S+)$/", $str, $matches );
  $flag = true;
  for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($matches[1]) - 1; $i++ ) {
      if( $matches[1][$i+1] < $matches[1][$i] ) {
          $flag = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($matches[2]) - 1; $i++ ) {
      if( $matches[2][$i+1] < $matches[2][$i] ) {
          $flag = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($matches[3]) - 1; $i++ ) {
      if( $matches[3][$i+1] < $matches[3][$i] ) {
          $flag = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  echo ( !$flag ) ? "ERROR" : "NO ERROR";
?>
```

Obviously, this is not the best/most-optimized of the solution.

Comment: I thought patterns from preg_match knows more than regular automation regex...i guess i'll have to parse it this way, thanks. Can you please explain me the pattern, by tags, as the logic of the automation.../^(\S+)\-(\S+)\-(\S+)$/   i got what it does but not how...

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a pretty decent resource for learning regex.